# Unable to pivot data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have an SQL query like

```
select name from customers where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

this will return me 5 rows.
What I am trying is

```
select Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5  from(select name from customers where id in (1,2,3,4,5)  
)d pivot( max(name) for names in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
 ) piv;
```

to convert these 5 rows into 5 columns.

But I am getting null values in columns.

[image]

I don't know where am I doing wrong.
Any kind of help , suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you have a possible syntax error `for names in`  the column `names` is not in your `select`  if you are getting null values after that, then you have no names in `customers` with `id in (1,2,3,4,5)` and `name in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)`

Comment: Are `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5` actual values for `name` in your `customer` table?  If they are not, you'll only get nulls for values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way, you are pivoting the name and selecting the name under value also so please first make is sure if there is a value for that ids and retrieve the value for which you are trying pivoting:

```
create table #customers(id int, name varchar(50), fee int) 
insert into #customers values
(1, 'Q1', 100),
(2, 'Q2', 200),
(3, 'Q3', 300),
(4, 'Q4', 400),
(5, 'Q5', 500),
(6, 'Q5',  600),
(7, 'Q5',  700)

select Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5  
from(select name, fee from #customers where id in (1,2,3,4,5)  
)d pivot(SUM(fee) for name in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
 ) piv;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5
100 200 300 400 500
```

What respective value you want to display under name, if you mention that then we can provide more exact solution for that. Hope you can change your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Man for your quick answer :)